# Interior ball condition in $C^2$ domains

Tags: analysis, reference-request

Why a $C^2$ domain satisfies the  interior ball condition? I accept a reference too. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please add some context?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284562/interior-sphere-condition?rq=1

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43169/smooth-boundary-condition-implies-exterior-sphere-condition

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Smooth boundary condition implies exterior sphere condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43169/smooth-boundary-condition-implies-exterior-sphere-condition)

Comment: Have you found a reference ? I would like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the function $\psi$ from  your previous question,   [A question about $C^2$ domain.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/741324/), and use its Taylor expansion of second order to obtain an upper bound $\psi(x)\le C|x|^2$ for small $x$. This will ensure that for small $r$, the sphere of radius $r$ centered at $re_n$, stays above the graph of this function.

Comment: Can you explain why does $\Psi(x)\leq C|x|^2$ for small $x$ imply that for small $r$, the sphere of radius $r$ centered at $re_n$, stays above the graph of this function? Thanks!